# The Drupal 7 requirements say MariaDB 5.1.44 "or higher". Is 10.3.7 supported?

Tags: 7, database

According to the information available, Drupal 7 supports MariaDB version 5.1.44 or higher, but which are the higher versions?

Does Drupal 7 support MariaDB version 10.3.7 or any higher versions?

Comment: The requirements say “or higher”. You do not believe that and you are asking for the real answer. Is that an accurate restatement of the question?

Comment: I'd like to clarify the higher versions of MariaDB that Drupal 7 supports. For instance, does Drupal 7 support MariaDB version 10.3.7 or any higher versions?